# Get li element onclick with pure javascript without applying onClick to each element

Tags: javascript, html

First of all I do not want to use jQuery, just pure javascript; please don't link to duplicate jQuery posts.

If I have a list like

```
<ul id="bulk">
    <li id="one"></li>
    <li id="bmw"></li>
</ul>
```

I want to get the id of the clicked list element.
I am aware I could add **onClick=""** to each element but the production list I have has 2000 entries and I think a better way exists.

**For example:**

If I had only one `li` element with `id='singular'` I could use the following javascript to get the ID clicked.

```
var li = document.getElementById('singular').onclick = function() { do something };
```

As there are thousands of `li` elements, this code won't work.

I have been able to get a list of the element names with the following javascript:

```
var bulk = document.getElementById('bulk');
var bulkli = tabs.getElementsByTagName('li');
//bulkli contains ["one", "bmw"];
```

but this does not tell me which one was clicked.

Comment: +1 for going in plain-JS

Comment: In the click event , look at the event object, it contains the target element.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could add an event listener to the parent `ul` and then use `e.target.id` to get the `id` of the clicked element. Just check to make sure that the clicked element is actually an `li` since it's possible you may not be clicking on one.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/t85koq05/)

```
var ul = document.getElementById('bulk');  // Parent

ul.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'LI'){
      alert(e.target.id);  // Check if the element is a LI
    }
});
```

---

As pointed out in the comments, this approach won't work when the child of an `li` is clicked. To solve this, you would need to check to see if the parent element of the clicked element is the one that the click event is attached to.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/r4hoxn5c/)

```
var ul = document.getElementById('bulk'); // Parent

ul.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var target = e.target; // Clicked element
    while (target && target.parentNode !== ul) {
        target = target.parentNode; // If the clicked element isn't a direct child
        if(!target) { return; } // If element doesn't exist
    }
    if (target.tagName === 'LI'){
        alert(target.id); // Check if the element is a LI
    }
});
```

Comment: Basicly yes, but what if there are children elements in `li`s?

Comment: @JoshCrozier This seems like the best approach, However why is it that when I replace *...('click', function(e){ }...* with a declared function like *...('click', myfun(e));...* it doesn't work?

Comment: @JoshCrozier Thanks, I am new with JS, the fact you didnt pass e to the function is weird to me, As for the nested LI I will not have nested so your first answer was good enough for me.

Comment: @gummage you pass the function pointer as the callback. If you pass myfun(e) then the return value of the function is passed. Thats why the above example is not (function(e){...})(e) which would be equivalent to what you tried.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this:

```
var link = document.getElementById("bulk");
attachEvent(link, "click", EventHandler);

function attachEvent(element, type, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    else element.attachEvent("on"+type, handler);
}

function EventHandler(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uhkn0k2x/11/)

This work if `li` has children` elements:

[**fiddle example with children**](http://jsfiddle.net/uhkn0k2x/10/)

Answer (score 2):

pass its id as parameter into the onclick-function.

```
this.getAttribute('id')
```

Comment: OP has mentioned he does not wish to use onClick for each element.