# Select element from listbox

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath, automation

How to select element from this list?

```
ClickElementByXPath("//li[contains(text(), 'Legnica')]");

ClickElementByXPath("//li[contains(., 'Legnica')]");
```

Nothing works

```
<ul tabIndex="-1" class="k-list k-reset" id="ArrangementsWN_BusinessUnitId_listbox" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" aria-live="off" style="height: 177px; overflow: auto;" data-role="staticlist" unselectable="on">
    <li tabIndex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="0">Jelenia Góra</li>
    <li tabIndex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="1">Legnica</li>
    <li tabIndex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="2">Opole</li>
    <li tabIndex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="3">Wałbrzych</li>
    <li tabIndex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="4">Wrocław</li>
    <li tabIndex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="5">Bielsko Biała</li>
    <li tabIndex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="6">Będzin</li>
    <li tabIndex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="7">Częstochowa</li>
    <li tabIndex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="8">Kraków</li>
    <li tabIndex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="9">Tarnów</li>
    <li tabIndex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="10">Obcy PGE</li>
    <li tabIndex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="11">Obcy ENEA</li>
    <li tabIndex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="12">Obcy ENERGA</li>
    <li tabIndex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="13">Gliwice</li>
    <li tabIndex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="14">Centrala</li>
    <li tabIndex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="15">TD Serwis</li>
    <li tabIndex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" unselectable="on" data-offset-index="16">Wykonawca obcy</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you want? Do you want to use the `li` that's been clicked on or for example show the index of the item? Maybe the answers to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26204120/get-li-element-onclick-with-pure-javascript-without-applying-onclick-to-each-ele) can help you.

Comment: i want to click on element

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure how to fix your problem. My last guess would be to change the `unselectable="on"` to `off`, but I doubt that that would be the problem.

Comment: Your `XPath` seem to be correct. Update your question with exact exception log and check whether list located inside an `<iframe>` element

Answer (score 0):

First you need to click the parent element, then wait for the required list item to be visible and then click on it. Im not familiar with C#, but the Java implementation would be along these lines:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ArrangementsWN_BusinessUnitId_listbox")).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(), 'Legnica')])));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(), 'Legnica')]")).click();
```

Comment: I am using this 'ClickElementByXPath("//*[contains(@aria-owns, 'ArrangementsWN_BusinessUnitId_listbox')]")'; but doesnt work

Comment: @Cathal, `ExpectedConditions.not` should wait until target element becomes **invisible**. Also note that `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.condition(locator))` not only waits, but returns web-element, so there is no need to search it again with `driver.findElement(locator)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
// Create a list containing all the elements from the HTML list.
IList<IWebElement> listOfElements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//ul[@id='ArrangementsWN_BusinessUnitId_listbox']/li"));
// Click on the desired element
listOfElements[1].Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to be able to define the element that you want to click in c# you can do it this way :

```
var options = _driver.FindElements(By.Class("k-item"));
driver.findElement(By.id("ArrangementsWN_BusinessUnitId_listbox")).click();

foreach(var element in elements) 
{
if(element.Text.Equals("option text")
  {
   element.click();
   }
}
```

i use this for a lot of kendo dropdowns in the code i test. it also allows me to select specific options rather than just the first one as i can insert anything into "option text"